# How to Unittest a Factory with dependencies

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, phpunit, tdd

How can I test my factory with the entity manager? I have an error because I need to make my container return an instance of a class created from `doctrine` ( I do not even know what there is returned).

How can I create a test that I can make pass?

```
// factory i want to test
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    $googleAppOption = $container->get(GoogleAppOptions::class);
    $em = $container->get('doctrine.entity_manager.orm_default');
    return new GoogleTokenHandler($googleAppOption, new GoogleTokenClient(), $em);
}

//test function
 public function testReturnsTokenHandlerInstance()
{
    $googleOptionsFactory = new GoogleOptionsFactory();
    $googleOptions = $googleOptionsFactory($this->container->reveal(), null);
    $this->container->get(GoogleAppOptions::class)->willReturn($googleOptions);
    $googleTokenHandlerFactory = new GoogleTokenHandlerFactory($this->container);
    $tokenHandler = $googleTokenHandlerFactory($this->container->reveal(), null);
    $this->assertInstanceof(GoogleTokenHandler::class, $tokenHandler);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Th fact that this is hard to test is a good sign that there is something smelly about this. In your case it's quite obviously the container being injected and then being used to locate services to work upon. I would recommend rewriting this class to inject both the OptionsFactory (or even better just the options) and the EntityManager as well as the dynamically created GoogleClient in the constructor. What you would arrive at is an invoke that pretty much looks like this:

```
return new GoogleTokenHandler(
    $this->optionsFactory,
    $this->tokenClient,
    $this->entityManager
);
```

As you can see you neither use the `$requestedName` nor the optional `$options` being passed to your `__invoke`. That's a bit odd, but that won't bother us with the tests. Now you can simply mock out the services in your test and check whether invoke returns the correct instance:

```
public function testFactoryInvokeReturnsInstance()
{
    $optionsFactory = $this->prophesize(OptionsFactory::class);
    $tokenClient = $this->prophesize(GoogleTokenClient::class);
    $entityManager = $this->prophesize(EntityManager::class);

    $factory = new MyFactory(
        $optionsFactory->reveal(),
        $tokenClient->reveal(),
        $entityManager->reveal()
    );

    $this->assertInstanceOf(GoogleTokenHandler::class, $factory->__invoke());
    // Alternatively you can use the __invoke-magic directly:
    $this->assertInstanceOf(GoogleTokenHandler::class, $factory());
}
```

You could do the same with your class but basically you would have to add a Container and then stub out the get-method for all of the services being fetched from it. For example you are missing the entity manager in your snippet. Should the GoogleTokenClient being created in your method require some arguments/options there is no way to mock that behavior and in fact you won't be able to switch it out without changing the code. Whereas by injecting it in the constructor you can just re-configure your container to pass in a different object.

For posterity, your complete factory would probably look something like this:

```
class Factory {
    private $optionsFactory;
    private $tokenClient;
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(GoogleTokenClient $tokenClient, ...)
    {
        $this->tokenClient = $tokenClient;
        ...
    }

    public function __invoke() { return new GoogleTokenHandler(...); }
}
```

Comment: but that means i need a factory to create my factory ?

Comment: or should i then use the service locator in my controller to create my TokenHanlderFactory ?

Comment: I don't see which factory would create a factory, but generally speaking - if there is some dynamicism involved - it can be useful to have a "FactoryFactory" and in Java codebases it's somewhat common (when some state is kept between requests). In your controller you could use the container to either get the Factory or with some DI-containers get the TokenHandler directly, e.g. with Symfony's Container: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html

Comment: Depending on how strict you are you could even inject the used services into the controller and use that just like a regular service. If not, the controllers are pretty much the only thing that legitimately should have access to the container. Even then they should do it sparsely to not end up with a controller doing too much